# How can I open a tab with URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've this tabs here:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

How can I refer now via the URL for example with a # to a specific tab? So that when I click a tab, the URL changes to the tab and when I reload the page or share the URL that the specific tab gets opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract an anchor from an URL like so:

```
function getAnchor() {
    return (document.URL.split('#').length > 1) ? document.URL.split('#')[1] : null;
}
```

Then on page load you can set the active tab to the respective anchor.
`location.hash.substr(1)` will return the same as above.

Comment: And this is the simplest solution?

Comment: Easier: `location.hash.substr(1)` will return the same.

Comment: Do you know how I can get this within PHP?

Comment: Mate? Maybe an idea?

Comment: Not sure you can do it with php since anchors are not posted to the server, but you can try something like `$url=parse_url("yourdomain.com/#city");
echo $url["fragment"]; //This variable should contain the city keyword`